# How to safely detect an horizontally flipped movieclip, against rotated ones?

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix

I have 2 movieclips on the Stage. One is rotated 180 degrees, and the other one is flipped horizontally (via the flip horizontal command). What I need to do is detect the one that is horizontally flipped.

I tried the following function from another answer ([Detecting a movieclip has been Flipped horizontally on the stage in as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577262/detecting-a-movieclip-has-been-flipped-horizontally-on-the-stage-in-as3)):

```
function isFlippedHorizontally( obj:DisplayObject ):Boolean
   {
    return obj.transform.matrix.a / obj.scaleX == -1;
   }

   trace( isFlippedHorizontally( yourObject ) );
```

...but it doesn't seem to work on this scenario, since it returns true on both cases.

Furthermore, is there any way to safely detect ONLY the flipping part, against the scale/rotate transformations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine an abstract example:

There are two circles with solid fill, so it makes no visual difference between flipped one and a rotated one.

 [image]

But in code we can clearly see the difference by using the Rotation and Scale value.
If the first circle is called `circle1` and second `circle2`. We can trace their scale value and rotation values:

```
trace(c1.rotation); // 180
trace(c1.scaleX); // 1
trace(c1.scaleY); // 1
```

and

```
trace(c2.rotation); // 0
trace(c2.scaleX); // -1 - flipped horizontally
trace(c2.scaleY); // 1
```

so the function for isFlippedHorizontally could look like this:

```
function isFlippedHorizontally(targetObject:DisplayObject):Boolean
{
    if (targetObject.scaleX < 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Note, this method assumes that if you stretch the flipped image it's still counts as flipped horizontally.

If you want to know if the object is ONLY flipped and not stretched and rotated, use this:

```
function isFlippedHorizontallyOnly(targetObject:DisplayObject):Boolean
{
    if (targetObject.scaleX == -1 && targetObject.rotation == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```